# Вывод всех постов произвольных таксономий по категориям

Tags: php, wordpress

Есть сайт на WordPress. Также есть код, который приведу ниже. На данный момент мне выводит список всех произвольных категорий. В каждом `<div class="cat-block">` выводится название категории, список постов внутри этой категории, ссылка на саму категорию:

```html
<div class="home-wrap">
  <div class="cat-block">
    <div class="cat-title">Категория 1</div>
    <div class="posts-list">
      <h3>Услуга категории 1</h3>
      <h3>Услуга категории 1</h3>
      <h3>Услуга категории 1</h3>
      <h3>Услуга категории 1</h3>
      <h3>Услуга категории 1</h3>
      <h3>Услуга категории 1</h3>
      <h3>Услуга категории 1</h3>
      <h3>Услуга категории 1</h3>
      <h3>Услуга категории 1</h3>
      <h3>Услуга категории 1</h3>
      <h3>Услуга категории 1</h3>
    </div>
    <a href="" class="btn">See more</a>
  </div>

  <div class="cat-block">
    <div class="cat-title">Категория 2</div>
    <div class="posts-list">
      <h3>Услуга категории 1</h3>
      <h3>Услуга категории 1</h3>
      <h3>Услуга категории 1</h3>
      <h3>Услуга категории 1</h3>
      <h3>Услуга категории 1</h3>
      <h3>Услуга категории 1</h3>
      <h3>Услуга категории 1</h3>
      <h3>Услуга категории 1</h3>
    </div>
    <a href="" class="btn">See more</a>
  </div>

  <div class="cat-block">
    <div class="cat-title">Категория 3</div>
    <div class="posts-list">
      <h3>Услуга категории 1</h3>
      <h3>Услуга категории 1</h3>
      <h3>Услуга категории 1</h3>
      <h3>Услуга категории 1</h3>
      <h3>Услуга категории 1</h3>
      <h3>Услуга категории 1</h3>
      <h3>Услуга категории 1</h3>
      <h3>Услуга категории 1</h3>
    </div>
    <a href="" class="btn">See more</a>
  </div>

  <div class="cat-block">
    <div class="cat-title">Категория 4</div>
    <div class="posts-list">
      <h3>Услуга категории 1</h3>
      <h3>Услуга категории 1</h3>
      <h3>Услуга категории 1</h3>
      <h3>Услуга категории 1</h3>
      <h3>Услуга категории 1</h3>
      <h3>Услуга категории 1</h3>
      <h3>Услуга категории 1</h3>
      <h3>Услуга категории 1</h3>
    </div>
    <a href="" class="btn">See more</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Проблема в том, что сейчас во всех категориях почему то выводятся не их посты, а посты с первой категории. Вот код вывода:

```
<div class="home-wrap">
  <?php $cats = get_categories(array('taxonomy'=>'services_cat')); // get list of categories
  foreach ($cats as $cat) { ?>
  <div class='cat-block'>
    <div class="cat-title"><?php echo $cat->cat_name; ?></div>
    <div class='posts-list'>

   <?php

      $custom_terms = get_terms('services_cat');
      $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'services',
        'tax_query' => array(             
             array(
                'taxonomy' => 'services_cat',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => $custom_terms[0]->slug,
            ),
         )
      );

     $query = new WP_Query($args);

     if ($query->have_posts()) {
        while ($query->have_posts()) {
           $query->the_post();
     ?>

     <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
           
     <?php
        }
     }
     wp_reset_postdata();
    ?>

    </div>
    <a href="<?php echo esc_url( $category_link ); ?>" class="btn"><?php _e('See more', 'crea'); ?></a>
  </div>
  <?php } ?>
</div>
```

Comment: в  вп не шарю, но мне кажется цикл надо было начать так `foreach ($cats as $i => $cat)` и в теле цикла юзать `$custom_terms[$i]->slug`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В этом участке ошибка.

```
$custom_terms = get_terms('services_cat');
      $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'services',
        'tax_query' => array(             
             array(
                'taxonomy' => 'services_cat',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => $custom_terms[0]->slug,
            ),
         )
      );
```

Нужно использовать данные из верхнего цикла foreach ($cats as $cat)

Нужно заменить фрагмент на

```
      $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'services',
        'tax_query' => array(             
             array(
                'taxonomy' => 'services_cat',
                'field' => 'id',
                'terms' => array( $cat -> term_id )
            ),
         )
      );
```

Comment: Совершенно верно, спасибо большое!